# Selected values in dropdown display two times in dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript dropdown it shows the selected  value and other values but the selected value display 2 times in dropdown  it should show ony 1 time.Pls any one help me to rectify the problem.eg.
if there is only 3 values 2013, 2014.2015and i select 2013
    but it shows     2013- selected value
                     2013
                     2013
                     2014
                     2015

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoYear() {
  var time = new Date();
  var year = time.getYear();

  if (year < 1900) {
    year = year + 1900;
  }

  var date = year - 1; /*change the '25' to the number of years in the past you want to show */
  var future = year + 10; /*change the '10' to the number of years in the future you want to show */ 

  document.writeln ("<form><select id='year_<?php echo $row->id ?>'  name='year_<?php echo $row->id ?>'  ><option value=\"\"><?php echo $row->year; ?>");
  do {
    date++;
    document.write ("<option value=\"" +date+"\">" +date+ "");
  }
  while (date < future)
  document.write ("</select></form>");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  autoYear();
</script>
```

Comment: This dropdown just displays years. Where do mango, apple, and orange come from? And using `document.write() is so 1990's -- please learn modern Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not closing your `<option>` tags.

Also, as mentioned in a comment above, there are far better ways to do this than manually writing out the tags with `document.write`. You are much more prone to creating errors when manually writing out HTML this way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has do with `do-while` loop. Because do while loop executes the content of the loop once before checking the condition of the while.So your value will displayed twice.

Whereas if you use  `while` loop it will check the condition first before executing the content, and will not executed prior to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a conditional in your loop to let it know that it needs to skip over the selected value, allow me to demonstrate below:

```
var date = year - 1; /*change the '25' to the number of years in the past you want to show */
var future = year + 10; /*change the '10' to the number of years in the future you want to show */ 

document.writeln ("<form><select id='year_<?php echo $row->id ?>'  name='year_<?php echo $row->id ?>'  ><option value=\"\"><?php echo $row->year; ?>");

do {
  date++;
  if (date != <?php echo $row->year; ?>) {
      document.write ("<option value=\"" +date+"\">" +date+ "");
  }
}
while (date < future);
```